# Make Home folder accesible to different installations

Tags: 12.04, 14.04, permissions

I just installed 14,04 next to 12,02 and I want to copy my home folder from my previous installation to my new one. I get permission errors (cannot read files). How to change that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this on superuser mode (root, or use sudo user), but it is not recommanded (low security level) :

```
chmod +r /path/to/your/old/folder -R
cp /path/to/your/old/folder /path/to/your/new/folder -R
```

or You can try this but also it is not recommanded (low security level):

```
chown nobody.nogroup /path/to/your/old/folder -R
```

or you can create linux user with same uid and gid in this case you can read your folder without problem.

Comment: Better to change ownership: sudo chown $USER:$USER /home/old/home/dir